# How to get the latest entries from a 2D array based on a condition/column using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the highlighted rows, which are the latest entries according to the timestamps of those PO number (col1/A)?

I started playing around trying `sort()`, but I can't apply it correctly:
**Dataset**

| OrderPO | TimeStamp | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TTL-220218 | 8/17/2022 20:47:55 | Print |
| TTL-220218 | 8/18/2022 7:49:49 | Print |
| TTL-220220 | 8/17/2022 18:00:55 | Print |
| TTL-220220 | 8/18/2022 9:49:49 | Print |
| TTL-220219 | 8/17/2022 20:47:55 | Print |
| TTL-220219 | 8/18/2022 7:49:49 | Print |
| TTL-220219 | 8/17/2022 20:47:59 | Print |
| TTL-220216 | 8/18/2022 8:30:49 | Print |

```
function getLastestEntries() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet28');
  let pos = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  let uniquePos = pos.map(e => e[0]);
  uniquePos = [...new Set(uniquePos)];

  let latests = [];
  uniquePos.forEach(function (record) {
    let filteredPo = pos.filter(e => e[0] == record);
    filteredPo.sort(function (a, b) {
      let latest = a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1;
      latests.push(latest)
    });
  })
  console.log('POS: ' + JSON.stringify(latests))
}
```

**Rows to be extracted:**

[image]

Appreciate directions!

Comment: Hi, @Kos! It sorts, but how to extract only the latest entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Latest Row for each PO based upon date

```
function getLastestEntries() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let rows = { pA: [] }
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let po = r[0];
    if (!rows.hasOwnProperty(po)) {
      rows[po] = [{ row: i + 1, date: new Date(r[1]), values: r.join(",") }];
      rows.pA.push(po);
    } else {
      rows[po].push({ row: i + 1, date: new Date(r[1]), values: r.join(",") });
      rows[po].sort((a, b) => {
        return new Date(a.date).valueOf() - new Date(b.date).valueOf();//sorts as it collects data in large data sets this would not be the best way.  You could sort when you display the output.
      });
    }
  });

  let html = `Latest Rows`;//using a dialog to display the output
  rows.pA.forEach(po => {
    let x = rows[po].reverse()[0];//this only needs to be done once
    let d = x.date;
    let v = x.values;
    let r = x.row;
    html += `<br>po: ${po}<br>latest Date: ${d}<br>Row: ${r}<br>values: ${v}<br><hr>`
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Latest Rows for Each PO")
}
```

Test Data:

| OrderPO | TimeStamp | Unit | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TTL-220218 | 8/17/2022 20:47:55 | Print | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| TTL-220218 | 8/18/2022 7:49:49 | Print | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| TTL-220220 | 8/17/2022 18:00:55 | Print | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| TTL-220220 | 8/18/2022 9:49:49 | Print | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| TTL-220219 | 8/17/2022 20:47:55 | Print | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| TTL-220219 | 8/18/2022 7:49:49 | Print | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| TTL-220219 | 8/17/2022 20:47:59 | Print | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| TTL-220216 | 8/18/2022 8:30:49 | Print | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |

Dialog Output:

[image]

Comment: I see it works nicely when it gets the data based on the background, but it reallly needs to be the latest entry of each OrderPo based on the timestamp. Thanks

Comment: Oh I believe you edited the question since I started writing this

Comment: Can you post the data as a table so we can copy it.  It should be an easy problem but I don't wish to type in all of the data by hand

Comment: So then the highlighting doesn't really matter

Comment: It was just to show which are to be extracted. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: There is the table (in the edited question). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Saw your comments on large datasets, which shall be the case. Thanks